# ASP MVC5 list/edit/view users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I'm simply trying to create a UserController that displays a list of the application's users. With edit/view and delete functionality.

The problem is that when I use the item.Id field in the model ApplicationUser some long id is shown that isn't accepted as a id parameter in the url.When I click edit, this message appears: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'DesignCrew.Controllers.UserController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameternaam: parameters

So, how can I fix this. Or is there a better way of managing users in ASP MVC5?

UserController:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = context.Users.ToList();
        return View(user);
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model List<DesignCrew.Models.ApplicationUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table-users">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 400px;">Naam</th>
        <th>Opties</th>
    </tr>


 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayName(item.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Your UserController Edit method requires Int32 parameter and you are trying to access it with out parameter. Show also the Edit method of the controller, is your parameter name "id" or what?

Comment: This is how it looks like:         public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: actually simplemembership ApplicationUser do not use id as unique key, instead it uses UserName, so change @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { UserName= item.UserName }) and controll method to public ActionResult Edit(string UserName) { return View(); }

Comment: Hi ijaz. With that controller code, the initial value is not being set in the input field rendered with @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.UserName). Do I need to pass the object in de action method? Sorry, i'm new to asp.net mvc. Btw, the username IS now supplied in the url /user/Edit/Username

Comment: I found a solution. Keeping the id field in the url and changing the action method paremeter "id" to type "string" made it work.

Answer (score -2):

I understood that you want to display yours USERS one by one  for EDIT

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var user = context.Users.Find(id);
    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful after almost 6 years. Also "code only" answers are not really helpful for anybody who might stumble over this.